# I am trying to ajax my floating menu asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a floating menu that works, but my problem is when I click on any link within the menu, it redirects to the requested data and the Menu disappears. An ideas how to ajax my menu so that it stay o the page. I am using ASP.Net

```html
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scriptFloatingMenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/floating-1.12.js"></script>

<div class="container body-content">
    <div class="box" style="position:relative; float:left; width:100px; min-height:1300px">
        <div id="floatdiv" class="box" style="position: relative; width: 96px; height: 120px">
            <h3>Genres</h3>
            <ul id="vertical" class="clearfix">
               
                @foreach (var genre in Model)
                {
                    <li id="clickme">
                        @Html.ActionLink(genre.Name, "Browse", "Store", new { Genre = genre.Name }, null)
                    </li>
                }
              
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    floatingMenu.add('floatdiv',
        {
            // Represents distance from top or
            // bottom browser window border
            // depending upon property used.
            // Only one should be specified.
            targetTop: 10,
            // targetBottom: 0,
            // prohibits movement on x-axis
            prohibitXMovement: true,
            // Remove this one if you don't
            // want snap effect
            snap: true
        });
</script>
```

Comment: And by ajax you mean that the menu should stay open?

Comment: Create a master page and put your menu inside ,

Comment: I don't want the menu to be on the master page. I want it to stay open on another page. thank you